# SaxonJS: not getting an real HTML DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, browser, saxon-js

I have a complicated stylesheet which when done executing should replace not just the body of the current html element, but the entire html element with all the children, head and body.

```
function applyStylesheetUsingSaxon() {
    SaxonJS.setLogLevel(10);
    options = {
      sourceText: getSourceXML(),
      stylesheetLocation: "spl.sef.json",
      destination: "document"
    };
    result = SaxonJS.transform(options);
    document.replaceChildren();
    document.appendChild(result.principalResult.firstElementChild);
}
```

When I do this, some FairAdBlocker extension will try to access document.body and get null and then nothing works any more. The produced html also does look suspicious.

I thought maybe I just get HTML as a string and can put it as innerHtml or so, with:

```
  destination: "serialized"
};
result = SaxonJS.transform(options);
```

the error I get is:

> Serializer does not support the requested HTML version: 1.0',

So how can I get a decent HTML DOM produced? Note, I can't use replaceBody because I need to replace the headers as well.

**MORE DETAILS:** I'm responding to some clarifying question in the comments:

> Is the DOM up to that approach to rip of all children from a document to then add a new root element?

This has worked just fine with the result from the built-in XSLTProcessor in Chrome.

> What does that talk about the extension mean, can you disable that and check whether your approach works without the extension interfering?

That extension issue is a red herring. The fact is that the document.body returns nothing after the replacement operation, and the nodes look differently.

> Also, what is a minimal but complete sample of XML input, XSLT, wanted HTML result and the "suspicious" HTML you say you get?

Here I show you the difference just looking at the output of the transform. This is debugging console output using the built-in XSLTProcessor

[image]

here is what comes from Saxon-JS:

[image]

and I guess the issue is that the result is a #document-fragment. Here is some view of the details looked at as javascript objects rather than as HTML. First what comes from the built-in XSLTProcessor:

[image]

and here is what comes from Saxon-JS:

[image]

> As for the serialization attempt, well, do you use the HTML output method with e.g. html-version="5.0" or no explicitly set version or html-version? The error sounds as if you set method="html" version="1.0".

Indeed we have

```
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" doctype-public="-"/>
```

which I think was to fiddle with quirks mode or something because of former need to be compatible to IE.

**IN SUMMARY:** I think the analysis of what we get out from the built-in XSLTProcessor (document) vs. Saxon-JS (document-fragment). If Saxon-JS actually was to produce a document and have an destination option to replace the entire document content, then it would be great. Not having that, I should still be able to make a workaround.

What I don't understand is why, when I take the root node () from the built-in XSLTProcessor result #document.firstElementChild and append it to the current (and empty) document, then that document.body property comes with the new body. But when I do the same with the Saxon-JS result #document-fragment.firstElementChild then the document.body returns null, despite the two .firstElementChild () root nodes being pretty much the same kind of thing in both cases. (Hard to tell the difference, but neither has a "body" property, both have two children,  and .

Comment: Can we use Iframe as a destination? HTML page will only have the Iframe which can be used as stylesheet container to dump the result of the transform.

Comment: Is the DOM up to that approach to rip of all children from a document to then add a new root element? What does that talk about the extension mean, can you disable that and check whether your approach works without the extension interfering? Also, what is a minimal but complete sample of XML input, XSLT, wanted HTML result and the "suspicious" HTML you say you get? As for the serialization attempt, well, do you use the HTML output method with e.g. `html-version="5.0"` or no explicitly set `version` or `html-version`? The error sounds as if you set `method="html" version="1.0"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have updated my question with more detail to answer your questions in the above comment.

Comment: If you don't have a `document.body` then your XSLT has produced an XML DOM document, not an HTML DOM one. Perhaps but the elements in the XHTML namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Here at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2022/replaceChildrenTest4.html is an example using Saxon-JS 2.3 to run a HTML DOM to HTML DOM transformation and then using your first approach of `replaceChildren()` to first remove the existing document's children to, in the second step, `appendChild` the result of the Saxon-JS transformation.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    .sample {
      color: red;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="../../Saxon-JS-2.3/SaxonJS2.js"></script>
    <script>
    function runXslt() {
      const xslt = `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <xsl:output method="html"/>
        <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
        <xsl:template match="meta[@charset]"/>
        <xsl:template match="style">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (contains(., 'red')) then replace(., 'red', 'green') else replace(., 'green', 'red')"/>
          </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
       </xsl:stylesheet>`;
       
       var resultFragment = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`transform(map {
         'source-node' : .,
         'stylesheet-text' : $xslt
         })?output`,
         document,
         { params : { xslt : xslt } }
      );
         
      console.log(resultFragment);
      
      document.replaceChildren();
      document.appendChild(resultFragment);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p class="sample">This is a test.</p>
    <input type="button" value="test" onclick="runXslt();">
  </body>
</html>
```

For debugging ease I have avoided the use of SEF and directly run the XSLT source code through `fn:transform` but I would think the same approach would work with a precompiled SEF and the SaxonJS.transform API. A test doing that is at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2022/replaceChildrenTest5.html and works the same.

Comment: Thank you for this. Your example helps me on many fronts. First you show how to use the Saxon-JS without having to compile that stylesheet, that's so much easier for debugging! Secondly you show how to do the async stuff correctly. Then you show that doing the switch with this result.principalResult fragment gets a document.body but when I follow your example with my transform I still get that document.body == null. But anyway, I have something to chew on.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow, as for the `body` being null, that is usually an indication that an XML DOM, not an HTML DOM was created; it might be necessary to ensure you put result elements into the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, to ensure they are recognized as HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is in the FairAdBlocker extension. The technique you outline works fine for me. My guess is that the FairAdBlocker detects the DOM change, probably when you do `removeChildren()` and throws an NPE which causes the JavaScript execution to stop (or something).

Here's a (somewhat crudely coded) solution that replaces the contents of the `head` and `body` elements without ever removing them. Perhaps the extension will let this pass...

```
function applyStylesheetUsingSaxon() {
    SaxonJS.setLogLevel(10);
    options = {
      sourceText: "<doc><title>Spoon!</title><para>Hello.</para></doc>",
      stylesheetLocation: "replace.sef.json",
      destination: "document"
    };
    let result = SaxonJS.transform(options)
    let newhtml = result.principalResult.firstChild;
    // Hack: we just assume that the current and generated pages
    // are rooted at html and contain a single head and a single body
    let oldhtml = document.querySelector("html");
    replaceChildren(oldhtml, newhtml, "head");
    replaceChildren(oldhtml, newhtml, "body");
}

function replaceChildren(oldelem, newelem, name) {
   let src = null;
   for (let pos = 0; pos < newelem.childNodes.length; pos++) {
     if (newelem.childNodes[pos].localName == name) {
       src = newelem.childNodes[pos];
       break;
     }
   }

   let tgt = null;
   for (let pos = 0; pos < oldelem.childNodes.length; pos++) {
     if (oldelem.childNodes[pos].localName == name) {
       tgt = oldelem.childNodes[pos];
       break;
     }
   }
   
   if (src == null || tgt == null) {
     // This should never happen…
     console.log("Failed to find " + name);
     return;
   }

   while (tgt.childNodes.length > 0) {
     tgt.removeChild(tgt.childNodes[0]);
   }
   while (src.childNodes.length > 0) {
     // This append removes the node from newelem
     tgt.appendChild(src.childNodes[0]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the entire document isn't our recommended approach: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!browser/result-documents

Can you say a little more about why you want to do it this way?

Comment: I appreciate that the design of Saxon-JS allows routing parts to different places in the page and I am excited to adopt this for interactive UI design too. After all, I live and breathe XSLT. But in this case we have a document stylesheet that has been used for over 10 years and we don't want to re-design this right now. It is rendering an XML document format to a complete page, and we need to set parts of the head as well as the body. Also, I didn't see anything in the text you reference that would say there is any drawback with making a complete HTML page in one run.

Comment: I'll do a little investigation. It's not recommended so it may not be well tested. I am, for a start, concerned about what replacing the `head` will do to the JavaScript environment of the page.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you put an id on the `html` element, say `whole-page`, and use `<xsl:result-document href="#whole-page" method="ixsl:replace-content">` does that work?

Comment: Can you simply remove `version="1.0"` from the `xsl:output` instruction? I was able to serialize the result and push it back into the browser with `document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = result.substring(...)`